# communication between pic18f4520 board and Visual basic application via UDP

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to communicate with application written in Visual basic. When i send data from application to board everything works perfectly, but in other direction it doesn't work. I do follow network traffic with wireshark and everything seems ok. When send data from board with PIC to application(PC) I can see it in wireshark, but I can't detect any data inside of application I think that my problem is at application , I am not very good at VB programming, not good at all..this is my first program.. I've attached code so you can see what I've done. Application(PC) ip address 192.168.1.11, pic ip address 192.168.1.10 (mask 255.255.255.0). So if someone could give me advice I would be very grateful..
PS. sorry for my bad english.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text.Encoding
Imports System.Text


Public Class Form1
Dim controlData() As Byte = {&H55, &H55, &H55, &H55, &H55}

Const portTo As Integer = 5000
Const portFrom As Integer = 5001

Dim udpTransmit As New Sockets.UdpClient(portFrom)
Dim udpReceive As New Sockets.UdpClient(portTo)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   btnTo.Click
    udpTransmit.Connect(tbToIp.Text, portTo)
    udpTransmit.Send(controlData, controlData.Length)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        Dim ep As New IPEndPoint(tbToIp.Text, portTo)
        Do
            Dim receiveData() As Byte = udpReceive.Receive(ep)
            text1.Text = ASCII.GetString(receiveData)
        Loop
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

[data form PIC to PC]
  [data from PC to PIC][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0KEw.jpg)